# How do I correct an illegal argument exception in Java?

Tags: java, exception, illegalargumentexception, nosuchelementexception

Whenever I open infile2.dat, the program produces me with the previous errors. I am not sure if the errors are within this class, or within the other. I've played around with it but cannot seem to figure it out. If anyone could help me out, I'd greatly appreciate it.

I am receiving the following errors in my code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
Just caught an illegal argument exception. 
Just caught an illegal argument exception. 
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
at testfor6.TestFor6.main(TestFor6.java:58)
```

Here is the code (it's long, I apologize in advance):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    /** holds answer of whether user has more inputs or not */
    char answer;
    /** holds the results when calling inLetter() */
    char letter;
    /** holds the results when checking for types/strings in txt file */
    char inType2;
    /** holds double results when searching line by line the text file */
    double inAmount2;
    /** holds the results when calling inAmount() */
    double amount;
    /** initiates infile to null */
    File infile2;
    /** count system for how many valid lines were read and used */
    int count = 0; 

    /** calls description method */
    description();
    /** initiates new Object */
    NewClass newInput = new NewClass();

    try{
        /** defines new variable linked to .dat file */
        infile2 = new File("GironEvent.dat");
        Scanner fstream = new Scanner(infile2);

        /** calls while loop. As long as there is a line, the loop continues */
        while(fstream.hasNext())
         {
             try
             {
                 /** inputs first string in line of file to variable inType */
                 inType2 = fstream.next().charAt(0);
                 /** inputs first int in line of file to variable inAmount */
                 inAmount2 = Double.parseDouble(fstream.next());

                 /** calls instance method with two parameters */
                 newInput.donations(inType2, inAmount2);
                 /** count ticket increases */
                 count+=1;
             }
             catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                 /** prints out error if exception is caught*/
                 System.out.println("Just caught an illegal argument exception. ");
             }
         }
         /** closes stream between program and fiel */
         fstream.close();
     } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        /** Outputs error if file cannot be opened. */
        System.out.println("\nGironEvent.dat could not be opened. ");
    }

        /** outputs line count, and totals per type */
        System.out.println("\n" + count + " number of valid lines were read!\n");
        System.out.println("Total Sales: " + newInput.getSale());
        System.out.println("Donations: " + newInput.getDonated());
        System.out.println("Expenses: " + newInput.getExpenses());   

    do{
        /** loop asks user if there is more that needs to be added to the totals. N exits loop. */
        System.out.print("\nAre there any more items to add that were not in the text file? (Type 'Y' or 'N'): ");
        answer = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        if ((answer == 'y') || (answer == 'y'))
        {
            letter = inLetter();
            amount = inAmount();

            newInput.donations(letter, amount);
        }

    }while (((answer == 'y') || (answer == 'y')));
    /** calls instance method to display totals in a fancy manner */
    newInput.display();
}

/** inLetter - displays types to user. Asks user to input type. Converts input into uppercase letter.
 * 
 * @return resultTwo - Uppercase form of result. Result is the type the user inputted.
 */
public static char inLetter(){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    char result;
    char resultTwo;

    System.out.println("T = Tiket Sales");
    System.out.println("D = Donations");
    System.out.println("E = Expenses");
    System.out.print("Please input an identifier ");
    result = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
    result = Character.toUpperCase(result);

    return result;    
}

/** inAmount - asks user for amount. Tests that amount isn't a negative number or a zero.
 * 
 * @return result - the amount the user inputed. regardless if it was the first or tenth time. 
 */
public static double inAmount(){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double result;

    System.out.println("Please input an amount ");
    result = keyboard.nextDouble();

    if(result <= 0){
        System.out.print("Please input a positive and non-zero amount ");
        result = keyboard.nextDouble();
    }

    return result;
}
/** description - displays a description of what the program does
 * void.
 */
public static void description(){
    System.out.println("The program will ask you what amount is being spent on what.");
    System.out.println("    ex: expenses, ticket sales, and profts.");
    System.out.println("This program will help determine whether the event generated or lost money.");      
}
```

-Manny

Comment: I could be wrong, but fstream might be a reserved keyword.

Comment: @DavidPulse let me change it, and I'll keep you updated. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidPulse Rubbish. If there was a compilation error, how could he possibly be executing the program and getting exceptions? FYI the list of Java keywords is defined in [JLS #3.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9), and it does not include `fstream`. It is the name of a library class in C++: not a keyword there either.

Comment: @OP So you wrote some code, ran it, provided some input, and caught some exceptions. So what's your question?

Comment: Your file structure seems to be broken. You're calling `hasNext` once, but `next` twice, so your file is different from your expectation.

Comment: @EJP I just would like clarification as to what the errors are referring to, so I can go back and correct them.